# SecureCookiePermission issue - Applet not working with latest Java 6 update 29

Tags: php, session, applet, java

In our website, we use applet which is not working after upgrading to Java 6 Update 29. Applet should communicate with server for storing data's to database. Applets works fine in lower of versions of Java (Update 22 or 26 or 27) and it's impossible to ask our clients to downgrade the java versions. I found some errors in Java console and I think java couldn't able to access/create cookie or session (some kind of permission issue). Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

```
network: Connecting http://www.example.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (com.sun.deploy.security.SecureCookiePermission origin.http://www.example.com:80)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.cookie.DeployCookieSelector.canServeCookies(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.cookie.DeployCookieSelector.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setCookieHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at ATutorApiAdapterApplet.ATutorCommit(ATutorApiAdapterApplet.java)
    at ATutorApiAdapterApplet.LMSCommit(ATutorApiAdapterApplet.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Server http://www.example.com/write.php requesting to set-cookie with "Coyote-2-8b928cf0=a000200:0; domain=example.com; path=/"
network: Server http://www.example.com/write.php requesting to set-cookie with "SESSION=1v1md9bphfvgrqal38vg5quba1; path=/"
ATutor cmi storage failed.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission http.strictPostRedirect read)
```

Answer (score 1):

Emm... I am not pretty sure but the line as

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (com.sun.deploy.security.SecureCookiePermission
>   origin.http://www.example.com:80)

perhaps says the applet is trying to access its sources as "cookies" or something with a wrong cookie policy settings or your applet is not signed.

... because cookies tut note says as

> You must sign your RIA JAR file in order to access cookies. See the
>   documentation for the jarsigner tool to learn how to sign JAR files.

To see more detailed information you can read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookiePolicy.html) and [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html)

Good luck

Comment: looks like latest Java bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that is supposed to be fixed in update 30

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7102914

However, I updated to the preview version of update 30 and still have the same problem.  The ONLY solution (amongst many things I tried) is to wrap any calls to make connections to the server in an AccessController.doPrivileged block using AllPermission.

```
Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
permissions.add(new AllPermission());
AccessControlContext context = new AccessControlContext(
        new ProtectionDomain[]{new ProtectionDomain(null, permissions)});

AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>()
    {
        @Override
        public Object run()
        {
            URL connecting code
        }
    }, context);
```